# Excel help regarding Array Formula and Sort

Tags: arrays, excel, sorting

I have created a excel sheet with multiple columns combining a mix of manual data entry, data validation dropdowns and array formulas to automate data entry.

eg. `{=IF(ROW(A2:A100}=2,"Name",IF(C2:C100<>"",$B$1,""))}`

which adds header and autopopulates column A with name specified in B1 for every non-blank cell in C.

The problem I am having is after the array formula has been applied I cant filter or sort the data without an error message appearing stating "You cannot change part of an array".

This defeats the purpose of array formula if the data has to stay fixed in its original position and requires the use for cell by cell calculations.

Comment: `=IF(ROW(A2:A100}=2` should be `=IF(ROW(A2:A100)=2`. This error message usually occurs when you've pressed Ctrl+Shift+Enter on a group of cells. You need to enter the formula with only one cell selected then copy to the rest

Comment: That is a design choice that seems pretty normal. When an array formula is used to generate a *range*, the results are much dependent on the order of the data; the sorting might change that order and invalidate the calculation, which again might make the sorting invalid. I general you should avoid array formulas that generate a range. You can easily avoid it in the example. On the other hand, formula arrays used for individual cells do not cause any sorting issue.

Comment: You can try to *fix* the values (remove formulas) before sorting if that's an option.

Comment: Doesnt selecting one cell and dragging the formula down render using Array Formula unnecessary? Are there any other alternatives to automate/auto-populate columns based on the function i created? The main purpose of sheet is a data entry point for other users to input their data and allow automation where possible.